React Native Expo+Metro bundled js with incorrect paths
Bundled js output uses /assets syntax, which on webOS simulator (not sure about the other platforms) is read as global path and results in request to file:///assets/

Adding . in the beginning of import fixes the problem by somehow forcing it to use relative path to index.html

Can't find any metro configurations to set that, don't really want to write custom script to re-write the file. How to achieve that?
